# AngularJS, Nested UI-View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uiview

Could someone give a hint on `ui-view`?
I have one main `ui-view` and then two nested views, but for some reason these two are not getting loaded.

```
$stateProvider

    .state('index',{
    url:'',
    templateUrl: './app/modules/main.html'
})
    .state('index.feed',{
    parent:'index',
    templateUrl: './app/modules/feed.html'

})
    .state('index.status',{
    parent: 'index',
    templateUrl: './app/modules/status.html'
    });
```

The main page is loading but the two other views not
in my main.html I have:

```
<div class="voucher-display" ui-view="index.feed"></div>
<div class="feed" ui-view="index.feed"></div>
```

I just get an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

The value you pass to ui-view in your html is not the name of the state, it should be the name of the view.

Is the html in feed.html and status.html supposed to replace or be displayed along with main.html?  Either scenario will change the solution, but assuming you always want main.html, and want to display the feed.html and status.html where their respective nested views are selected, you'd do something like this:

```
.state('index', {
  url: '/',
  views: {
    'main': {
      templateUrl: './app/modules/main.html'
    }
  }
})
.state('index', {
  views: {
    'main': {
      templateUrl: './app/modules/main.html',
    },
    'detail': {
      templateUrl: './app/modules/feed.html'
    }
  }
})
.state('index.status', {
  views: {
    'main': {
      templateUrl: './app/modules/main.html',
    },
    'detail': {
      templateUrl: './app/modules/status.html'
    }
  }
});
```

And in your html you'd need two div tags that map the view.

```
<div ui-view="main"></div>
<div ui-view="detail"></div>
```

Now main.html should always show up in the first div, and feed.html or status.html, when their states are active, will show up in the second div.

Here is the docs for the [ui-view directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view), and here is a [good blog post](http://www.funnyant.com/angularjs-ui-router/) about ui-view.

Comment: It didn't work, because I have the index.html and from the I call the main.html, and those "status", "feed" I call them from inside main.html. something like..

-index.html
-- main.html (main ui-view)
--- status.html (status uiview)
--- feed.html (feed uiview)

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of attempts, this worked to load the nested:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: '',
        views: {
            'main': {
                templateUrl: './app/modules/main.html'
            },
            'status@index': {
            templateUrl: './app/modules/status.html'
            },
            'feed@index':{
            templateUrl: './app/modules/feed.html'
            }
        }
})
```

index.html has:

```
<main ui-view="main"></main>
```

and inside the main.html I have:

```
<div class="voucher-display" ui-view="feed"></div>
<aside ui-view='status'></aside>
```

but now I got another problem, if I want to load another ui-view from my index.html, what should I do? because this does not work:

```
.state('clients',{
        url:'/clients',
            templateUrl:  './app/modules/clients.html'
        });
```